# DomainCollectionView not changing pages

Tags: silverlight-5.0, wcf-ria-services

I'm trying to download lage amout of items from server and to avoid timeouts I'm using paging so what I tried to do is to load the first page and in my DomainCollectionView Loaded method call MoveToNextPage and so on untill all pages are loaded.

When I do that the DCV does not change from page, it remains on page 0, then I tried to refresh inside the PadeChanged event of the DCV but in there the PageIndex is -1 abd when I refresh the load operation is automatically cancelled.

this is my code:

```
private void OnLoadedPrintingModels(LoadOperation<AppointmentModel> op)
    {
        if (op.HasError)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ApplicationStrings.PrintingConnectionError + Environment.NewLine + op.Error.Message);
            op.MarkErrorAsHandled();
            this.downloadDialog.Close();
            this.TotalPrintCountD = 100.0;
            this.downloadDialog = null;
            this.printingList.Clear();
            this.printingDomainList.Source = null;
        }
        else if (!op.IsCanceled)
        {
            if (op.Entities.Any())
            {
                printingList.AddRange(op.Entities);
                if (this.isStartingPrinting)
                {
                    this.TotalPrintCount = op.TotalEntityCount;
                    this.TotalPrintCountD = (double)op.TotalEntityCount;
                    this.isStartingPrinting = false;
                }
                isDownloaded = true;
                printingDomainList.Source = op.Entities;
                printingDomainView.SetTotalItemCount(op.TotalEntityCount);

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ApplicationStrings.NoSearchResults);
                isStartingPrinting = true;
                this.downloadDialog.Close();
                this.TotalPrintCountD = 100.0;
                this.downloadDialog = null;
                this.printingList.Clear();
                this.printingDomainList.Source = null;
                DownloadedPrintingItems = 0.0;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ApplicationStrings.PrintOperationCanceledByUser);
            this.downloadPrintDataCanceled = false;
            this.downloadDialog.Close();
            this.TotalPrintCountD = 100.0;
            this.downloadDialog = null;
            this.printingList.Clear();
            this.printingDomainList.Source = null;
            isStartingPrinting = true;
            DownloadedPrintingItems = 0.0;
        }
    }
    bool isDownloaded = false;
    void printingDomainView_PageChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (isDownloaded)
        {
            isDownloaded = false;
            DownloadedPrintingItems = 100.0 * (double)printingList.Count / this.TotalPrintCountD;

            if (printingList.Count < this.TotalPrintCount)
            {
                using (this.printingDomainView.DeferRefresh())
                {
                    this.printingDomainView.PageSize = PrintingPageSize;
                    this.printingDomainView.MoveToNextPage();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                isStartingPrinting = true;
                this.downloadDialog.Close();
                this.downloadDialog = null;
                DownloadedPrintingItems = 0.0;
                ConfirmPrintingResults();
            }

        }
    }
```

I'm trying to do many things here but nothing seems to work. Any help on how to do this will be very appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem by waiting for DomainCollectionView.IsChangingPage inside a thread using async and await, the resultant code is this:

```
private **async** void OnLoadedPrintingModels(LoadOperation<AppointmentModel> op)
    {
        if (op.HasError)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ApplicationStrings.PrintingConnectionError + Environment.NewLine + op.Error.Message);
            op.MarkErrorAsHandled();
            this.downloadDialog.Close();
            this.TotalPrintCountD = 100.0;
            this.downloadDialog = null;
            this.printingList.Clear();
            this.printingDomainList.Source = null;
        }
        else if (!op.IsCanceled)
        {
            if (op.Entities.Any())
            {
                printingList.AddRange(op.Entities);
                if (this.isStartingPrinting)
                {
                    this.TotalPrintCount = op.TotalEntityCount;
                    this.TotalPrintCountD = (double)op.TotalEntityCount;
                    this.isStartingPrinting = false;
                }
                printingDomainList.Source = op.Entities;
                printingDomainView.SetTotalItemCount(op.TotalEntityCount);

                **await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {
                        while (printingDomainView.IsPageChanging)
                        {
                            Thread.Sleep(1);
                        }
                    });**

                DownloadedPrintingItems = 100.0 * (double)printingList.Count / this.TotalPrintCountD;

                if (printingList.Count < this.TotalPrintCount)
                {
                    using (this.printingDomainView.DeferRefresh())
                    {
                        this.printingDomainView.PageSize = PrintingPageSize;
                        this.printingDomainView.MoveToNextPage();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //this.IsBusy = false;
                    //this.WaitingMessage = ApplicationStrings.WaitLabel;
                    isStartingPrinting = true;
                    this.downloadDialog.Close();
                    //this.TotalPrintCountD = 100.0;
                    this.downloadDialog = null;
                    DownloadedPrintingItems = 0.0;
                    //Thread.CurrentThread.Join(1);
                    ConfirmPrintingResults();
                }

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ApplicationStrings.NoSearchResults);
                isStartingPrinting = true;
                this.downloadDialog.Close();
                this.TotalPrintCountD = 100.0;
                this.downloadDialog = null;
                this.printingList.Clear();
                this.printingDomainList.Source = null;
                DownloadedPrintingItems = 0.0;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ApplicationStrings.PrintOperationCanceledByUser);
            this.downloadPrintDataCanceled = false;
            this.downloadDialog.Close();
            this.TotalPrintCountD = 100.0;
            this.downloadDialog = null;
            this.printingList.Clear();
            this.printingDomainList.Source = null;
            isStartingPrinting = true;
            DownloadedPrintingItems = 0.0;
        }
    }
```